# Javascript File to Blob

Tags: javascript, file, blob

I'm recording an audio into an empty file using Cordova Media.

To upload it I need to have the content type on the file.

I'm trying to convert the File into a Blob so I can set the content type, however I'm struggling to convert the File into a blob

```
state.cordova.localDirectory.getFile(filename,{create:true, exclusive:false},
    f => {
      const options = {
        SampleRate: 16000,
        NumberOfChannels: 1,
      }
      media = new window.Media(f.nativeURL,() =>
        f.file(file => {
          const blob = new Blob(file,{type: 'audio/m4u'}) <--  Trying to convert file into a blob here
          blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date()
          blob.name = filename
          console.log(blob)

          upload(blob,'audio/m4u')
            .then(data=> {console.log(data);store.dispatch(voiceAudioUploaded(sessionId,gameTaskId,data))}, err=> console.log(err))
        }
          , err => console.log('err',err) ))
      media.startRecordWithCompression(options)
    })
```

Error is `

> Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable.

`

Comment: Blob expects an iterable (e.g an Array). I don't know what `file` is, but it seems it's not iterable. Note that if it is a `File` as in the web API `window.File`, then it's already a Blob. But if you really wanted to make it just a Blob, for I don't know what reasons, then you'd do `new Blob([file], options)`.

Comment: Yes it's a window.File, To set the content type

Comment: if there is another way of setting the content type let me know

Comment: Why do you need to set the content-type?

Comment: because it doesn't have it and the upload function needs the file to have the contentType

Comment: And why does this upload function need it... Anyway, instead of creating a Blob, create a new File from this File: `file = new File([file], file.name, {type: 'application/foo'})`

Comment: thanks that's a good answer. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
const blob = new Blob([file],{type: 'audio/m4u'})
```