# How to generate a PDF File (just as a File) using html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jspdf, html2pdf

I am working on a **React** project.

Here, I am trying to generate a PDF file (invoice) and upload it to Google Drive.

following code shows how I tried to create the file but I could not get the PDF file I needed. I would like to know how to generate the PDF file using html2pdf.js lib.

```
    function createPDF() {
    console.log('create PDF function works!');
    let element = document.getElementById('report_component');
    let opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'my-invoice.pdf',
        image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98},
        html2canvas: {scale: 2},
        jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'}
    };

    // New Promise-based usage:
    // window.html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save(); // I do not want to save/download the PDF using the web browser.

    // I want to get the PDF file. I tried like this;
    let value = window.html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).toContainer().toCanvas().toImg().toPdf().output();

    // const blob = new Blob([value], { type: 'application/pdf'});
    let file = new File([value], 'my-invoice.pdf', {
        type: 'application/pdf',
    });

    /* Here I try to implement the code to upload the PDF file to Google Drive.
    * First I need to get the PDF File. */
    console.log(file);

}
```

Comment: Could you be more spesific about your problem?

Comment: You probably want to send a blob? Look at the answer here: [Javascript File to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646331/javascript-file-to-blob)

Comment: I have provided an answer to this question and I demonstrated what my requirement is. It will show how I approached my requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If any one searching an answer for this question. here it is;

I wanted to create a report(invoice) using HTML. Below you can find how I designed my invoice.

Note: Please note that I included html2pdf.js as a script in HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Invoice</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section id="my_invoice">
    <!-- I designed the invoice here -->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of the existing code tutorials show us to download the generated PDF. Following JavaScript code will help you to download the PDF. When you run this code, browser will open a window and asks where to download this PDF file. Then, you can save the PDF file easily.

```
let element = document.getElementById('my_invoice');
let opt = {
  margin:       1,
  filename:     'my-invoice.pdf',
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
};

// New Promise-based usage:
html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();
```

But my requirement was slightly different. I just wanted to create the PDF file. Then, do something with that file. In my scenario, I wanted to upload that generated PDF file to Google Drive. Following code segment shows how I use html2pdf.js to generate the PDF file(blob). Please note that I used .outputPdf() method to get the blob. For more information, you can refer to the [html2pdf.js Worker API documentation](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/).

```
  /** Creates the PDF report document.
     * @return Promise: resolves if PDF report generates successfully,
     * otherwise rejects. */
    function createPDF() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('create PDF function executed!');
            let element = document.getElementById('my_invoice');

            let opt = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: 'my-invoice.pdf',
                image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.95},
                html2canvas: {scale: 2, useCORS: true},
                jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait'}
            };

            try {
                const blob = await window.html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).outputPdf('blob', 'my-invoice.pdf');
                resolve(blob);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });

    }
```

Hope you learnt something. Cheers!